# Raspberry Pi Pandas/Numpy ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies: import numpy from source directory

Tags: python, pandas, raspberry-pi, importerror

I was doing `import pandas as pd` and immediately got the ImportError.

**Error message:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/projects/.../pm_venv/pd_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/home/projects/.../pm_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
        its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
        your python interpreter from there.
```

I'm confused about the message as I'm not *importing numpy from its source directory*?

---

My machine is a Raspberry pi 4 with Raspbian 11 Bullseye (aarch64).

Python version: 3.9.2 (running in a virtualenv)

Pandas version: 2.1.3

Numpy version : 1.26.2

---

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.Dataframe()
```

I've tried running the code in and out of the venv. And I've install Pandas with `pip install pandas` and `sudo apt-get install python3-pandas`. And I got the same error message no matter what.

---

What I've searched:

[(raspberrypi) ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies: numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74205727/raspberrypi-importerror-unable-to-import-required-dependencies-numpy)

[Azure ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies: numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59123792/azure-importerror-unable-to-import-required-dependencies-numpy)

[ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies: numpy - Raspberry Pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77374261/importerror-unable-to-import-required-dependencies-numpy-raspberry-pi)

Comment: maybe you should reinstall `numpy`. It may need also install some C/C++ libraries using `apt`

Comment: answer in [python - Explain why numpy should not be imported from source directory - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570011/explain-why-numpy-should-not-be-imported-from-source-directory) suggestd that it may need to install C modules used by `numpy`.

Answer (score 2):

I have also faced the same issue. So I uninstalled numpy by this command "pip uninstall numpy" and then reinstalled using this command "pip install numpy --user" then the issue got resolved for me.